# How to fix this error: Too many positional arguments (1)?

Tags: command-line

```
FASTA file: /home/farhana/Desktop/Long Assignment/seqfasta.fa
FASTA type: protein
Proceed? [y/n] (Default: y): y
Enter a database title or will use 'seqfasta': seqfasta.fa
Enter taxid (optional): 
USAGE
  makeblastdb [-h] [-help] [-in input_file] [-input_type type]
    -dbtype molecule_type [-title database_title] [-parse_seqids]
    [-hash_index] [-mask_data mask_data_files] [-mask_id mask_algo_ids]
    [-mask_desc mask_algo_descriptions] [-gi_mask]
    [-gi_mask_name gi_based_mask_names] [-out database_name]
    [-blastdb_version version] [-max_file_sz number_of_bytes]
    [-logfile File_Name] [-taxid TaxID] [-taxid_map TaxIDMapFile] [-version]

DESCRIPTION
   Application to create BLAST databases, version 2.8.1+

Use '-help' to print detailed descriptions of command line arguments
========================================================================

Error:  (CArgException::eSynopsis) Too many positional arguments (1), the offending value: Assignment/seqfasta.fa
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Long and Assignment in line 1 are interpreted by the Bash shell as too many positional arguments, 2 instead of 1. Instead enclose the whole path in quotes like this:
`'/home/farhana/Desktop/Long Assignment/seqfasta.fa'`
or connect Long and Assignment with a connecting character like this `Long-Assignment` to make it a single positional argument instead of two separate arguments. You can also escape the space character between *Long* and *Assignment* by preceding it with a backslash `\` which makes it not interpreted by the shell as a special character.